# php Composer : what is BootStrap process?

Tags: php, composer-php, bootstrapping

the detail is as links : http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading

> Besides downloading the library, Composer also prepares an autoload file that's capable of autoloading all of the classes in any of the libraries that it downloads. To use it, just add the following line to your code's bootstrap process:
>   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

I don't know what "**your code's bootstrap process**" is.

Answer (score 2):

It's a generally used term for *"stuff your code has to do to be ready to run"*.

> **boot** |bo͞ot|
>
> verb [ with obj. ]
>
> ...
>
> *3* start (a computer) and put it into a state of readiness for operation: *the menu will be ready as soon as you boot up your computer* | [ no obj. ] : *the system won't boot from the original drive.*
>
> [from **bootstrap.**]

Comment: I think I know what the sentence means, but I don't know which file it means.

Comment: Whatever file is executed to start your app. There is no one specific file, it's up to you. The point is you need to include the `autoload.php` file **somewhere at the start of your code**.